# How to get inner child value based on another child in firebase real-time data base

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am designing an application using android studio and firebase. Please see the structure of my database here:

[image]

Here I have a parent `Sellers` node in that seller id as immediate child. Each seller Id contains the details of the seller like `name`, `Shop Type` and `token`.

Here in figure I have shown two sellers with shop type as `CarshowRoom` and one is having `ShopType` as `supermarket` (Actually there are many sellers and want to loop through all sellers).

I like to retrieve device token of sellers if they have a particular `ShopType`, for example if the seller have `ShopType` as  `car showroom` I like to get the value of token.

For that I write the code like

```
query=sellerRef.child("Sellers").orderByChild("ShopType").equalTo("CarShowRoom");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

      String sellerToken= snapshot.child("token").getValue().toString();
        Toast.makeText(SendEnquiryActivity.this, sellerToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

But my code is not working, any body please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your `onDataChange` will need to handle this list, by looping over `snapshot.getChildren` with something like this:

```
query=sellerRef.child("Sellers").orderByChild("ShopType").equalTo("CarShowRoom");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) { //  Add this loop
        String sellerToken= child.child("token").getValue(String.class); //  Read values like this
        Toast.makeText(SendEnquiryActivity.this, sellerToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
      throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```